# grails setting domain relations

Tags: grails, relationship

So, there are hasMany and belongsTo. For example, i have a class like this:

```
class Book {

String name

static belongsTo = [creator:User]

}
```

I can do this: `new Book(name:"some name")`. But can i set creator like this?

```
def user = new User(name:Bob)
def book = new Book(creator:user)
```

or later `book.creator = user` ?

Does the `creator` behave like a field?

What if there would be a hasMany, for example:

```
class User {

String name
String password
static hasMany = [createdBooks:Book]

}
```

Does the createdBooks here behave like an array that i can access via `user.createdBooks.add(book)` method?

---

I give up, apparently there is something wrong with this code:

```
    def book = new Book(name:params.bookName)

    book.creator = session.user
    book.save()
    session.user.createdBooks.addTo(book)
    session.user.save()
```

There are no exceptions, but on startup my index page is shown as 404 not found. This part of code breaks everything, i am completely lost what and why is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first example, an AST transformation adds a `User creator` property, and in the second it adds a `Set createdBooks` property. Both are added to the bytecode, not the metaclass, so these properties are callable by Java, which is important because Hibernate knows nothing about GORM and can only work with real methods and fields.

You can set the creator like you're doing and also directly add to the `createdBooks` collection, but using the `addTo` and `removeFrom` methods do more than that - they initialize the collection if it's null, and also set the back-reference in the Book class for you to keep the in-memory as close as possible to what will be in the database after saving.

EDIT, based on updated question:

You can do most of what you describe, but there's basically no reason to since what you want to do can be done the "normal" way. You don't seem to have a Java/Groovy background - I'm guessing JavaScript since you want everything to be an array? That's great - you'll get this soon enough. But avoid trying to force your expectations on how the code should work, unless you're experimenting to see what works and how it breaks when it does, and you shouldn't complain too much when you try to do things that don't look much like the online reference docs. The addToBooks/removeFromBooks dynamic methods are what you're looking for, but the docs also provide an understanding of the big picture.

Read [the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) and get one or two good starter books. There are several referenced at in the [Books page](https://grails.org/books) at grails.org. "Grails 2: A Quick-Start Guide" is a the easiest to get started with, and The Definitive Guide and Grails in Action are also very readable but very comprehensive starting with an introduction to Groovy and working through all of the core features. All 3 have sample apps you can work as you read.

Comment: Thanks Burt! It became obvious to me also, that i need to start from the basics!